# Поиск внешних ссылок Jquery

Tags: jquery, ссылки

Нашёл скрипт на хабре, который ищет все внешние ссылки:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
    if (!a.test(this.href)) {
        // что-то делаем
    }
});
```

Проблема в том, что он выбирает не только внешние, но и те у которых просто есть id или скрипт прописан в href.

Есть ли у кого нормальный скрипт, что бы искал чисто внешние ссылки?
Или что добавить в этот?

Comment: _просто есть id_ - это какие ссылки? Вида `<a id="test" href=""></a>`? Так данный код смотрит только на `.hash` ссылки - на ID элемента он не смотрит.

Comment: Нет, типа <a href="#id"></a>

Comment: Возможно, тогда стоит добавить в проверку наличие `http://` или `https://` в начале ссылки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот хороший [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/suVrB/)

```
function linkify(inputText) {
var pattern = /([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)?)/gi;
var replacedText = inputText.replace(pattern, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
return replacedText;
}

var div = $('div'),
    txt = div.text(),
    newTxt;

newTxt = linkify(txt);
div.html(newTxt);
```

Для Вас его можно переписать например вот так:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').each(function() {
       var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
       var e = /([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)?)/gi
       var b = new RegExp(e);
       if (this.href && b.test(this.href) && !a.test(this.href)) {
          $(this).css({
            "backgroundColor" : "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.27)",
            "padding" : "3px",
            "border" : "1px #f00 dashed",
            "opacity" : "1 !important",
            "display" : "inline-block !important"
          });
       }
    });
})
```

Тут происходит выбор всех элементов **a**, у которых есть атрибут **href**, и этот атрибут является url ссылкой, которая ведет на другой домен.

Comment: Хороший пример выбора внешних ссылок, пример грамотно сделанной регулярки.